# Counterfeit coin, conditional probability

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, conditional-probability

I am doing Problem AT9 [[ Harvard-MIT Math Tournament February 27, 1999 ]] here: https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/1999/feb/adv/solutions.pdf

> As part of his effort to take over the world, Edward starts producing his own currency. As part of an effort to stop Edward, Alex works in the mint and produces 1 counterfeit coin for every 99 real ones. Alex isn’t very good at this, so none of the counterfeit coins are the right weight. Since the mint is not perfect, each coin is weighed before leaving. If the coin is not the right weight, then it is sent to a lab for testing. The scale is accurate 95% of the time, 5% of all the coins minted are sent to the lab, and the lab’s test is accurate 90% of the time. If the lab says a coin is counterfeit, what is the probability that it really is?

I'm confused by the part that says:

> The scale is accurate 95% of the time, 5% of all the coins minted are sent to the lab

If the scale is accurate 95% of the time, shouldn't the percentage of coins minted sent to the lab be$$(.01)(.95) + (.99)(.05) = .059?$$And not 5% as asserted?

Comment: You think that fake coin plus inaccurate scales means the coin is accepted as genuine. In real life that would be unlikely, the scales would have to have exactly the opposite error of the coin.

Comment: You would have thought the lab should be better than the scales

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Organizers have given the Solution , which uses "Subjective Interpretation" of the Question. I do not agree with the Solution , because **I think the Question itself is very ambiguous , & OP is rightly confused**.
The Question & the Answers are not up to the Quality Standards.

Eg 1 : "and only **.95%** of the coins **are** sent to the lab **and** counterfeit" should be "and only **95%** of the coins are sent to the lab **are** counterfeit"

Eg 2 : "**5%** of all the coins minted **are** sent to the lab" : Why ? because they failed the test ? or because of a quota ?

Eg 3 : "Since the mint is not perfect" : How imperfect is it ?

Eg 4 : "none of the counterfeit coins are the right weight" : Does this mean all real coins are the right weight ? Or is it Possible that real coins too have Deviations ?

Eg 5 : "Scale is accurate 95% of the time" : Provided the weight must be "$X$" , everything else is "not $X$" , this itself will Partially indicate the number of coins to be sent to the lab.

### My Solution :

When we have $100000$ coins with $1000$ counterfeit coins , then $99000 \times 0.05 = 4950$ real coins will fail the Initial Check & $1000 \times 0.95 = 950$ counterfeit coins will fail that Initial Check.
We can not tell what happens to the other $50$ counterfeit coins whose weights are wrongly reported by the Scale : the "Subjective Interpretation" is that those counterfeit coins get magically reported with right weight.

Total coins sent to lab $4950+950=5900$

[[ It is matching what OP is rightly asking that "it must be .059 , not 5% as asserted" ]]

The lab then checks those coins. It is $90%$ accurate.
Hence , among real coins , $4950 \times 0.10 = 495$ are Wrongly reported.
While , among counterfeit coins , $950 \times 0.90 = 855$ are Correctly reported.
Here too the "Subjective Interpretation" is that the other $95$ counterfeit coins magically get reported with Correct weight.

Thus , Probability that "when a coin is reported counterfeit , it really is counterfeit" is **$855 / (855 + 495) = 855 / 1350 = 19/30$**

### SUMMARY :

Question given is ambiguous.
Answer given $19/28$ is wrong.
OP is right about it being confusing & wrong.
Answer must be $19/30$ , though it is necessary to make "Subjective Interpretations" to the Question.
Question should be reworded to make it rigorous & less ambiguous.
Answer should then be updated to match the Question.

### ADDENDUM :

Normally , when Correct weight is $X$ & the coin has Wrong weight $Y$ , the Scale & the lab may wrongly report $Z$.
That is not the Case here !
The Scale & the lab are magically converting Wrong weight $Y$ to Correct weight $X$.

Comment: There is another interpretation of the question that supports the given 19/28 answer: See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: "99000×0.05=4950 real coins will fail the Initial Check": this assumes that all the real coins have the correct weight. The question strongly implies that even some of the real coins have the wrong weight. ("**Since the mint is not perfect,** each coin is weighed before leaving.")

Comment: That is what I said in my Point (Eg 3) & Point (Eg 4) , @MJ713 , though the HMTT Answer given assumes otherwise. When we want to go in that Direction , we must know the failure rate of the mint , which is not given. The HMTT Question is heavily muddled !!

Comment: I'm guessing that the assumption is that the scale and lab are set up for go/no-go testing. That is, they're not reporting a numeric weight, but simply a green or red light (or other binary indicator) meaning "pass" or "fail".

Comment: Correct , It is an unstated assumption by the HMMT Question , @R.M. , there are too many assumptions to make it highly ambiguous. I gave a "Binary Indicator" in my Comment here [ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717840/counterfeit-coin-conditional-probability/4717992#comment9994165_4718263 ] where we check whether  "the good coin weight is more than 10g" or "the bad coin weight is less than 10g" to get true or false. There is a lot to reword in the HMMT Question !

Answer (score 2):

Question Maker View:
Assume '5% of all the coins minted are sent to the lab'

It is given by the question and it means that 5% of coins will be sent to the lab, it is just a total amount and it is fixed by the qusetion. It is viewed as the estimation.

Why only .95% of the coins are sent to the lab and they are counterfeit:
not the right weight: 1% and
scale: 95%
Multiply to get 0.95%

As 5% of all the coins minted are sent to the lab,
so there is a 19% chance that a coin sent to the lab is counterfeit.

This value 19% chance comes from the calculation $\dfrac{0.95}{5}*$100% = 19%.

---

Assume the weight of real coin is x. And there exists only two types of coins, real and counterfeit coins.

real:99%, counterfeit:1%

Since the weighing scale is accurate 95% of the time, divide the weighing parts into 4 cases.
Case 1. real and correct weighing: 99% * 95% -> not sent to lab

Case 2. real and incorrect weighing: 99% * 5% -> sent to lab

Case 3. counterfeit and correct weighing: 1% * 95% -> sent to lab

Case 4. counterfeit and incorrect weighing: 1% * 5% -> sent to lab is unknown (unknown part)

Unknown part: if weight of counterfeit coin is $y\neq x$, it is possible that the counterfeit coin is weighted x incorrectly. Then it will not be sent to lab.
If we combine part 2,3, it can been seen that $99\%*5\%+1\%*95\%>5\%$.

From Question Maker View, he assumes that '5% of all the coins minted are sent to the lab' and it is an estimation of
case 2,3 and 4.

So I agree with the solution of Prem more than the solution of Question Maker.

Comment: The $19\%$ does not match the answer given $19/28$ , which itself is wrong. Basically the Question is ambiguous [[ More Details are there in my Answer Post ]]

Comment: No, the $19%$ here is to help him to think about the solution, I was not giving a full answer to the problem,  I only want to explain the part that he was confused.

Comment: I think the important part is to interpret the statement "5% of all the coins minted are sent to the lab",  and the author of this problem has a different view from you, let me review the problem.

Comment: Oh right , I got your Point , thank you for Correcting my reading of your Post ! The rest of my Comment about the HMMT still stands.

Comment: When you say "Different view" , that is what I mean with "Subjective Interpretation" : The Question is ambiguous with lots of assumptions.

Comment: I agree that the Question itself is very ambiguous, because it is too short for giving a real problem, I am also confused about that and use much time to think about what the author mean.

Comment: Correct ! I will leave you with One Point to think about : When real coin weight should be 10 , counterfeit coin has weight 9 , Scale is giving wrong weight 8 , will it report counterfeit or real ?!

Comment: I think it should be focused on whether it will be sent to the lab, as the  lab’s test is not 100% accurate. In your case, this counterfeit coin will be sent to the lab.

Comment: [[1]] It should be sent to lab , but Question Maker thinks a counterfeit 9 coin will wrongly weigh 10 (weight 8 is not at all considered) , to then count towards real coin & not sent to lab ! [[2]] When lab gets a counterfeit 9 coin , then wrong weight is 10 (weight 8 is not at all considered) , it will again count towards real coin !

Comment: I get your points and update my answer. It is in the case 3 and 4, I think it is just an estimation in the view of Question Maker. It is not good at all.

Comment: I like the update to your Post , thank you , +1 , I will make this last Comment [[ Math Stack Exchange is warning about too many Comments here ! ]] about "the mint is imperfect" : We should be given how "imperfect" the mint is , otherwise we can not make the right calculations to get the right conclusions. Eg if the mint is already making 20% bad coins , then the new 1% will not matter much , while if the mint is making 0.0003% bad coins , then the new 1% will matter more.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the mint produces a million coins.  Of these, 10,000 (1%) are counterfeit, and 990,000 are real.

We are given that the scale used to determine whether to send a coin to the lab is 95% accurate.  Assume that the same inaccuracy applies equally to false positives and false negatives.  Then, 9,500 counterfeit coins will be sent to the lab.

Since there are a total of 50,000 (5%) coins sent to the lab, then there must be 40,500 real coins sent to the lab alongside the counterfeits.  (Some will be incorrect-weight coins flagged correctly, and some will be correct-weight coins flagged incorrectly, but it doesn't matter what the breakdown of these is.)

Assume that the lab's 90% accurate rate applies independently to false positives and false negatives.  Then:

- $(0.90)(9,500) = 8,550$ counterfeit coins will be correctly detected as counterfeit.
- $(0.10)(9,500) = 950$ counterfeit coins will incorrectly pass as real
- $(0.90)(40,500) = 36,450$ real coins will correctly pass as real.
- $(0.10)(40,500) = 4,050$ real coins will incorrectly be detected as counterfeit.

So the lab will detect 12,600 coins as counterfeit, of which 8,550 actually will be.  The conditional probability in question is thus $\frac{8550}{12600} = \frac{19}{28} \approx 0.678571$.

Comment: This is what Question Maker wanted to try , but the Question got heavily muddled. (1) In this "Subjective Interpretation" , we see that 99% are good & 1% are bad. In HMTT Question , it says mint is imperfect + 1% is intentionally bad , which implies more than 1% will be bad in total ! (2) When Correct weight is measured wrongly , it will be wrong. When Wrong weight is measured wrongly , it might rarely be correct & most likely it will still be wrong. HMTT assumes that Wrong weight measured wrongly is always Correct ! HMTT Question has a lot of Issues !

Comment: @Prem: In an earlier draft of my answer, I tried a different interpretation of "95% accuracy" that would have required at least 59,000 coins to be sent to the lab (as per OP's calculation), but since that's more than 50,000, I rejected it as a contradiction.  I agree that the question could have been worded better.

Comment: The Question Maker should have concentrated on Accuracy , rather than "Click-Bait" , with lines like "As part of his effort to take over the world, Edward starts producing his own currency" & then , "Alex" will be totally unnecessary. Your way was almost the way I was think about rewording the Question. [[ My way was "The mint generates good coins ( which are heavier than 10g ) & bad coins ( which are lighter than 10g ) according to the given Percentages. The Scale & the lab will sometimes incorrectly show light coins as heavy & heavy coins as light according to the given Percentages & ETC" ]]

Answer (score 0):

> The scale is accurate 95% of the time, 5% of all the coins minted are sent to the lab, and the lab’s test is accurate 90% of the time.

The use of the term 'accurate' is not very accurate here. The errors and inaccuracies can be of different kinds. We can have

- false positives: for a coin that is not a counterfeit, the scale/test detects a counterfeit.
- false negative: for a coin that is a counterfeit, the scale/test does not detect a counterfeit.

In these type of problems it is often assumed that both cases occur with the same rate (5% in this case).

> If the scale is accurate 95% of the time, shouldn't the percentage of coins minted sent to the lab be$$(.01)(.95) + (.99)(.05) = .059?$$And not 5% as asserted?

I imagine that the problem was supposed to be computed as you did and consider false positive and false negative rates of 5%.

Then the 5% coins that are sent to the test is a mistake and should indeed be 5.9%.

---

However, you can have a situation with 5% inaccuracy *and* 5% of the coins being sent to the test.

Let's look at it in a contingency table:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
&\text{actually positive} & \text{actually negative}& \text{total} \\ \hline
\text{weighted positive} &x&4+x&4+2x\\
\text{weighted negative} &1-x&95-2x& 96-2x\\\hline
\text{total}&1&99&100
\end{array}$$

If we set the true positives cell (actually positive and weighted positive) equal to $x$ then the other 3 cells are all based on $x$ because of the following three conditions

- fixed marginals for total truly positives
- fixed marginals for total truly negatives
- the diagonal, sun of false positives and false negatives, equals 5%

And with a fourth condition we can also fix $x$

- the total number of positive weighted cases is 5%. ($4+2x = 5$)

Then $x = 0.5$.

This means that with a false negative rate of $\frac{1}{2} = 0.5$ and a false positive rate of $\frac{1}{22} \approx 0.045$ your total rate of error will be

$$0.01 \frac{1}{2} + 0.99 \frac{1}{22} = 0.05$$